# Latest Raspbian 10.28.2012 perl issues

Tags: raspbian, perl

I can't install new version of CPAN or modules on it, how to solve it?

```
cpan[2]> cpan[2]> install CPAN
Running install for module 'CPAN'
Running make for A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-1.9800.tar.gz
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirror.atlantic.net/pub/CPAN/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-1.9800.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-1.9800.tar.gz ok
Uncompressed /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AN/ANDK/CPAN-1.9800.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/bin/tar xf "CPAN-1.9800.tar":
Couldn't untar CPAN-1.9800.tar
Package seems to come without Makefile.PL.
  (The test -f "/root/.cpan/build/ANDK-FSxrjj/Makefile.PL" returned false.)
  Writing one on our own (setting NAME to CPAN)
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
 ANDK/CPAN-1.9800.tar.gz                      : unwrapped NO -- untar failed
```

Answer (score 3):

You may break Debian's packaging system if you install modules from CPAN. There's some discussion about it on PerlMonks: [What is the best way to install CPAN modules on Debian?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=753416). Alternatively (and untested by me) there's [debian.pkgs.cpan.org](http://debian.pkgs.cpan.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can install a user perl using perlbrew. You can then install modules directly from cpan without the risk of breaking things. You can install perlbrew using `apt-get perlbrew`